# Ordenar resultados por numero de coincidencias en tabla relacionada

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Tengo dos tablas de mysql, la tabla clientes y la tabla viajes.
Me gustaría poder ordenar la tabla de clientes en función del numero de viajes que tenga cada cliente.
Cada cliente puede tener 0 o múltiples viajes

```
tabla clientes 
id, name

tabla viajes
id, id_cliente
```

He estado buscando código acerca de consultas relacionadas en laravel, pero nada se parece a lo que intento conseguir.

Comment: Un cliente puede realizar muchos viajes y un viaje puede ser realizado por muchos clientes, Te da como resultado una relacion muchos a mucho. puedes crear una tabla intermedia que almacene con los siguientes campos
id
idcliente
idviaje Consultas esa tabla y puedes traer los clientes y los viajes de esos clientes.
Dime si esto es lo que quieres y te aporto una idea mas clara codificada utilizando las relaciones de laravel

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar esto:

```
$cliente = Cliente::select(DB::raw('clientes.id, clientes.name'))
        ->leftjoin('viajes','clientes.id','=','viajes.id_cliente')
        ->groupBy('clientes.id')
        ->orderBy(DB::raw('COUNT(viajes.id)'), 'DESC')
        ->get();
```

Y obtienes

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si consultas tu base de datos veras que se obtuvo los registros y se ordeno de acuerdo a la cantidad de viajes realizados

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: justo lo que necesitaba, muchísimas gracias.